# Nokogiri and Mechanize help (navigating to pages via div class and scraping)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, mechanize

I need help clicking on some elements via div class, not by text of link, to get to a page to scrape some data.

- Starting with the page http://www.salatomatic.com/b/United-States+125, how do I click on each state's name without using the text of the link but by the div class?
- After clicking on a state, for example http://www.salatomatic.com/b/Alabama+7, I need to click on a region in the state, again by div class, not text of the link.
- Inside a region, www [dot] salatomatic [dot] com/c/Birmingham+12, I want to loop through, clicking on each of the items (11 mosques in this example).
- Inside the item/mosque, I need to scrape the address (at the top under the title of the mosque) and store/create it in my database.

UPDATES:

I have this now:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get("http://www.salatomatic.com/b/United-States+125")    


#loops through all state links
page.search('.subtitleLink a').map{|a| page.uri.merge a[:href]}.each do |uri|
  page2 = agent.get uri

        #loops through all regions in each state
        page2.search('.subtitleLink a').map{|a| page2.uri.merge a[:href]}.each do |uri|
            page3 = agent.get uri

            #loops through all places in each region
            page3.search('.subtitleLink a').map{|a| page3.uri.merge a[:href]}.each do |uri|
             page4 = agent.get uri

                      #I'm able to grab the title of the place but not sure how to get the address b/c there is no div around it.
                       puts page4.at('.titleBM')

                      #I'm guessing I would use some regex/xpath here to get the address, but how would that work?

                      #This is the structure of the title/address in HTML:

                      <td width="100%"><div class="titleBM">BIS Hoover Crescent Islamic Center </div>2524 Hackberry Lane, Hoover, AL 35226</td> This is the listing page: http://www.salatomatic.com/d/Hoover+12446+BIS-Hoover-Crescent-Islamic-Center

            end
        end             
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to make sure the `a[:href]`'s are  converted to absolute urls first though.
Therefore, maybe:

```
page.search('.subtitleLink a').map{|a| page.uri.merge a[:href]}.each do |uri|
  page2 = agent.get uri
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps me navigate to page to page as I used about in my UPDATED post, but I still need to figure out how to extract the address b/c there is no direct div around it...please see my updates above for more details.

Comment: Looks like: `page4.at('.titleBM').next.text`

Comment: Thanks that worked to get the address, now just need to figure out how to parse it with regex and store in the db :)

Comment: If they're all US addresses then it's straightforward, otherwise consider geocoding

Comment: Yup, US addresses for example: 
"901 East First Street, Tucson, AZ 85719"

I want to put street into 1 variable, city 1 variable, state 1 variable and zipcode into 1 variable.

Can you elaborate on straightforward please? :)

Comment: Looks like: `/(.*), (.*), ([A-Z]{2}) (\d{5})/`

Comment: How can I iterate over each element with '.subtitleLink a'? Right now it's only doing some and not all elements...

Comment: I tried this:

page2.search('.subtitleLink a').each do |x|      
  x.map{|a| page2.uri.merge a[:href]}.each do |uri|
    page4 = agent.get uri
  end

Comment: But I get this error:

rake aborted!
can't convert Symbol into Integer
/Users/farooqyousuf/Projects/HalalSpot/lib/tasks/something.rake:19:in `[]'

Comment: It should be doing all of them. If not start a new question about it.

Answer (score 0):

For the pages of US and regions you can do:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.salatomatic.com/b/United-States+125')
page.search("#header a").each { |a| ... }
```

Here inside the block you can find corresponding link and click:

```
page.link_with(text: a.text).click
```

or ask mechanize to load the page by href:

```
region_page = agent.get a[:href]
```

Inside the region you can do the same, just search like

```
page.search(".tabTitle a").each ...
```

for Tabs (Restaurants, Markets, Schools etc.) And like

```
page.search(".subtitleLink a").each ...
```

How to find these things? Try some bookmarklets like SelectorGadget or similar, dig in HTML source code and find common parents/classes for links you are interested in.

UPDATED getting page by href as @pguardiario suggested

Comment: I like Chrome's elements panel personally. For following urls, try simply: `agent.get a[:href]`

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I'm on the right track. I've edited my post up top with updates and have another question too.